# Access Rows and Columns in Python Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
t = [[0],[1]]
```

I wanted sum of the row and column if the matrix is actually one-dimensional:

```
s1 = sum(t[0][:])
s2 = sum(t[:][0])
```

I get both `t[0][:]` and `t[:][0] = 0` whereas these should be lists, the first row and the first column.

i.e. `t[:][0]` should have been `== [0, 1]`

How can I get the sums and the column and row accesses correctly?

Comment: `t[:][0]` is same as `t[0]` suppose you have `t=[[0],[1],[2]]` then `t[:2] == [[0],[1]]`

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat thanks, how can i get column as a list?

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way,

suppose your input is:

```
t=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

```
#sum of row 
[sum(x) for x in t]

#sum of columns
col_sum=[]
row_length = len(t[0]) #row length 
for idx in range(row_length):
  s=0
  for i in range(len(t)):
   s +=t[i][idx]
  col_sum.append(s)
```

Note:
`t[:][0]` is same as `t[0]` suppose you have 
`t=[[0],[1],[2]]` 
then 
`t[:2] == [[0],[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9]]
>>> 
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> def row_sum(_list,row_idx):
    return sum(_list[row_idx])

>>> row_sum(a,0)
6   #summation of 1st row i.e 1+2+3
>>> def col_sum(_list,col_idx):
    cols=list(zip(*_list))
    return sum(cols[col_idx])

>>> col_sum(a,0)
12 #summation of 1st column i.e 1+4+7
>>> col_sum(a,1)
15 #summation of 2nd column i.e 2+5+8
```

---

Here's a numpy approach.

```
import numpy as np
a=[[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [7,8,9]]
a=np.array(a)
def nprow_sum(_list,row_idx):
    return sum(_list[row_idx])
def npcol_sum(_list,col_idx):
    return sum(_list[:,col_idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using list comprehension:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

sums_by_row = [sum(row) for row in matrix]

sums_by_col = [sum([row[icol] for row in matrix]) for icol in range(len(matrix[0]))]

print(sums_by_row)  # [6, 15, 24]

print(sums_by_col)  # [12, 15, 18]
```